# How to find expected profit using the table of probabilities for each profit amount?

Tags: probability

I am very bad at formatting, so apologies for the messy text up ahead. I need to calculate the expected profit for a probability of two products A and B.

I have a table in my question with three columns :

$$\begin{matrix}\text{Probability} &\text{Profit Per Unit in Product A}& \text{Profit Per Unit in Product B}\\
0.15 & €15 & €0\\
0.2 & €20 & €10\\
0.3 & €30 & €35\\
0.3 & €35 & €40\\
0.05 & €50 & €70\end{matrix}$$

Would I be correct in saying that the anticipated profit for Product A is $$(0.15)(15) + (0.2)(20) + (0.3)(30) + (0.3)(35) + (0.05)(50)$$

I am very bad at probability so any help at all is very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yep you are correct.

Comment: Yes. Note that the formal terminology is *expected*, not *anticipated*.

Comment: Where is the "Continuous Probability" here?